# What does it mean by "made a national champion of"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

"Although the chip battle may have pre-dated Mr Trump, his presidency has intensified it. He has made a national champion of Qualcomm, blocking a bid for it from a Singaporean firm for fear of Chinese competition. "

What's the meaning of "He has made a national champion of Qualcomm, blocking a bid for it from a Singaporean firm for fear of Chinese competition?"
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The sense is that President Trump protected Qualcomm from a possible takeover in the  interest of the nation.

> ***[National champion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_champions)*** is a governmental policy in which large organizations are expected not only to seek profit but also to "advance the interests of the nation".

(Wikipedia)

Comment: +1 I was unaware of said gov policy nomenclature.